# XML document - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, google-maps

I'm working on a website where I need a google map to display the positions of the members of the site.

However, i'm having a bit of trouble getting data from the returned XML document when using the HTTP Geocode Service. When I put the string into the browser it returns the XML just fine and if I set a textbox.Text to the documents InnerText it also displays as it should. But when I want to extract values from nodes, it says object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm doing it this way:

```
string address = m.getProperty("adresse").Value.ToString();
string zip = m.getProperty("postNummer").Value.ToString();
string city = m.getProperty("by").Value.ToString();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + zip + "+" + city + "+" + address + "+DK&sensor=true");

XmlNode latNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeoCodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
XmlNode lonNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeoCodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");

// The error occurs when the code hits these:
string lat = latNode.Value;
string lon = lonNode.Value;
```

I must admin that I haven't worked that much with XML in C# yet, so any hint will be greatly appreciated! :-) Should also say that the above code is in a foreach loop, looping through the members of the site.

Thanks a lot in advance!

All the best,

Bo

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to paste how I get the values! ;)

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code.

Comment: Edited my post - missed out a few lines of code :) sorry about that!

Comment: Please show your sample xml, may be the nodes are null, or your path is wrong

Comment: Hey Saeed, my sample XML can be found here: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=8963+Auning+Torvegade 2B+DK&sensor=true

Comment: Ops, that didn't go too well posting the link :/ just add "2B+DK&sensor=true" after the actual link :)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you mentioned that the code is in a foreach loop and this loops through all members?  How many members are we talking about here?  Because that is potentially a lot of calls to the geocode service and that will make your map display time extremely slow.  Are you caching the lon/lat? Or maybe storing it once you have retrieved it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get latNode and lonNode ? It seems to be those that are null.

Since you are doing it in a loop, does any of the members succeed ? Perhaps you are not getting a hit for some of the addresses, so the lat/long nodes in the document might not be there ?

There really is no way to tell the exact problem from the code you posted. Use your debugger, and step through the code to see why you are not getting latNode assigned.

## Edit

This works:

```
XmlNode latNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
XmlNode lonNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");
```

You had a little type in the path. "code" in "GeocodeResponse" should be lowercase. XPath is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi driis, thanks for tuning in :) I would love to be able to use my debugger, but since this is a usercontrol made for use in Umbraco CMS, that's out of question :( I tried to put an if-statement around the next lines in my code to check if the lat and lon strings are equal to string.Empty, but still no data is showing up :/

Comment: Running under Umbraco shouldn't be a problem when debugging. (I have used Umbraco).

Comment: Perfecto! :) didn't see the capital C.. guess it's time to take a break then and come back with fresh eyes. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 4):

Replace "GeoCodeResponse" with "GeocodeResponse"

Please note the capital C in Code is incorrect. Xml is case sensitive.